# OpenERP many2many fields - python

Tags: python, odoo

I have the table: Employees, which contains only the field 'name' and 'login' (it's associated to the table users)

```
class Employees(osv.osv):
    _name = 'Employees.Employees'
    _columns = {
         'the_name':fields.char('Name:', size = 50),
         'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'User:', select = True),
     }
Employees()
```

Example:

'John' -> 'John@gmail.com'

'Marilyn' -> 'marilyn@outlook.com'

Then I have the table: Tasks, which contains the fields 'name', 'description', and 'employees_id'. When a task is created it could contain **several employees** for the same task, that's why I choose the "many2many" because I could select several employees.
So, I have tried the following:

```
class tasks(osv.osv):
    _name = 'tasks.tasks'
    _columns = {
          'the_name':fields.char('Name', size = 50),
          'description':fields.text('Description'),
          'employees_id':fields.many2many('Employees.Employees', 'Employees', '???', 'user_id', 'All Employees')
     }
tasks()
```

Example:

'Carry sand' -> 'Carry the whole sand from the beach' -> 'john@gmail.com; marilyn@outlook.com'

'Play' -> 'Play with legos' -> 'john@gmail.com'

But I don't know what to put on "???"..thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fields.many2many('other.object.name',
                     'relation object',
                     'actual.object.id',
                     'other.object.id',
                     'Field Name')

Example

```
'category_ids':
   fields.many2many(
    'res.partner.category',
    'res_partner_category_rel',
    'partner_id',
    'category_id',
    'Categories'),


 'employees_id':fields.many2many('employee.employee', 'employee_user_rel', 'user_id', 'employee_id', 'All Employees')
     }
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the third Field Like :-

```
'employees_id': fields.many2many('Employees.Employees',
                                 'tasks_employees_rel',
                                 'employee_id',
                                 'task_id',
                                 'All Employees')
```

for Employee... 
it will create another table which contains the fields `'employee_id', 'task_id',`

you can easily retrieve these values by just looping on this that is

task_obj.employees_id:
it will return List of employees associated with underline ta